# CURL's equivalent in Python

Tags: python-3.x, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to write curl's equivalent in my Python code.

```
curl -i -u username:password -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8" -X POST -d '{"id_no":"7877"}' https://host/XXXX/ -k
```

Where, I have username,password and host details with me.

My Python code is as below:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}
parameter = {'id_no': 7877}
p_response = requests.post(url,auth=('username', 'password'), headers=headers,params=parameter)
```

However, I'm getting below error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='host', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /id_no/?id_no=7877 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:748)'),))
```

Can someone suggest me the changes?

Answer (score 1):

You used the `-k` flag in the curl command (which tells it not to verify SSL) but you did provide the corresponding kwarg for `requests.post`.

Use `verify=False`.

Also, since you used the `-d` flag with `curl`, you need to use the corresponding `data` kwarg with `requests`.

```
p_response = requests.post(url, auth=('username', 'password'), 
                           headers=headers, data=parameter,
#                                           ^
                           verify=False)
#                          ^
```

[`curl` docs](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> -k, --insecure
>
> (TLS) By default, every SSL connection curl makes is verified to be
>   secure. This option allows curl to proceed and operate even for server
>   connections otherwise considered insecure.
>
> The server connection is verified by making sure the server's
>   certificate contains the right name and verifies successfully using
>   the cert store.
>
> See this online resource for further details: 
>   https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
>
> See also --proxy-insecure and --cacert.

[`requests` docs:](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification)

> Requests can also ignore verifying the SSL certificate if you set
>   verify to False:

Comment: That helped me to get rid of SSL issue, however, now I'm getting "InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings" error. But, when I hit the server using curl, I'm getting proper response. Any idea?

Comment: @Sumit `requests` is **warning** you because you are using `https` but not verifying the SSL certificate. You are still getting a "proper" response. `curl` could have issue a warning when using the `-k` flag but chose not to. It says nothing about the response.

Comment: Even if I ignore/supress warning, response is "Response 400" from Python. But CURL gives me actual data. I used urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning) to suppress warning. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Try to pass the `parameter` dictionary with the `data` kwarg instead of `params`

Comment: `data` will form-encode your post data. Why don't you use the `json` parameter (and skip the headers)?